# How to create css skins (using extend)

Tags: html, css, less

I have to create a skin for a WP theme, so I need to group all the selectors that have similar properties together (for example 'color').

Any advice how can I create something like a CSS skin with Less?
I ended up with this solution...

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
   &:extend(.heading-color);
   font-size: 12px;
}

.another-selector{
   &:extend(.heading-color);
   font-size: 24px;
}

.heading-color{
        color: red;
}
```

this outputs:

```
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.another-selector {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.heading-color,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
.another-selector {
  color: red;
}
```

This perfectly works except that I need to create a 'fake' class '.heading-color'.

Comment: For this very case, you probably don't even need an extend. It can be done like [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/ngsDH) also. Note that this wouldn't create any extra classes in the CSS output.

Comment: Yes for sure, but what I first need is a singolar property to group all similar selector, in my example I have the 'color:red' repeated only on time. More easy to override with a CMS and so on.

Comment: I doubt if such bloating result is worth "overriding with a CMS" (So if originally you needed 3 classes and 99 properties you'll have to generate 99 selector groups instead?) There're should be other ways of doing this (but it all depends on what exactly you mean by "overriding with a CMS"). Either way it is possible to eliminate such dummy classes by moving them into a separate file imported with  [`reference`](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-reference) option. See [for example](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/blob/master/articles/rbgi.md#method-3-emulating-1177)

Comment: And I still wonder why I would care of just one dummy identifier per each group when each of these groups already has to have tens of such identifiers :).

Comment: Generally working in the development of themes tend to create selectors with maybe the accent color or other elements (sorry I meant the use of the term CMS). It is not so important to have a dummy declaration, in most love to know if there are other ways to 'lead' elements with common characteristics together. Thanks for the tip I will try with 'reference'.

Comment: i do not understand why you can't use a variable in this situation; `@fontcolor: red` and use `color: @fontcolor`; in your selectors

Comment: I need a way to automatically group selectors that have same properties to create than for example modifcable skins from a WP admin... I largely use variables...

Answer (score 1):

You can write your "fake classes" in a separate `.less` file and then use `@import (reference)`.

fake.less:

```
.fake {
  color: red;
}
```

real.less：

```
@import (reference) "fake.less";

.real {
  &:extend(.fake);
}
```

real.css:

```
.real {
  color: red;
}
```

Sass supports **placeholder** which is more handy in this kind of scenario. Less contributors have been considering to implement similar features (with high priority, see https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1177) for over a year...so I think the workaround above maybe helpful for you.